# Scius as the name for a company

Tags: vocabulary

After a long time looking for Latin names for the name of my startup, I came up with "Scius", which from what I was reading means cognizant. This will be a company in the area of data science. So I'd like to make sure with you guys whether this would be an appropriate name. Thanks!

Comment: You may want to check if the name is available for a registered company https://beta.companieshouse.gov.uk/company-name-availability in the UK, and also if a suitable domain name is available.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The adjective *scius* means "knowing", "have knowledge", "someone who knows".
It comes from the verb *scire*, "to know", and is not semantically far from the present participle *sciens*.
If you want to convey that your company has knowledge, using this adjective is a good idea.

However, you should pay some attention picking the form.
Is it masculine, feminine, or neuter?
Singular or plural?
Latin has also case inflection, but I would stick with nominative.
If you want your company to be a masculine entity — which is particularly relevant if you want the name to refer to you in person — then the singular masculine *scius* is the way to go.
If you want it to be a general thing rather reference to a person, I would suggest the singular neuter *scium*.
If you want there to be an implicit noun like "[a] knowledgeable [machine]", then the gender and number depend on the noun.
For this particular example it would be *machina scia*.

Of course, there are also non-Latin aspects worth considering.
Does the name sound good?
Is it easy to pronounce and distinguish?
What other words in other relevant languages does it look or sound like?
The weight of these questions is for you to consider.
*Scius* is certainly reasonable, but I urge you to consider the other forms seriously.

Comment: This is perfect. Thanks a lot for your insights!

Comment: About non-Latin aspects: As someone who stumbled in here from the side-bar, my initial understanding of "Scius" was "Sci-US", as in "Science, USA". Your company is about Computer Science, so if USA is your primary area of operation, then I'd say you're all set.

Comment: @Fax: That's interesting. I suspect people from other countries would not have thought of that? I certainly wouldn't. There are like a million words from Latin ending on *-us*, and which are widely used in all European languages including English, so...

Comment: @Cerberus It may be because you're a Latin scholar and I'm not, but I would suspect a company name to be an abbreviation before suspecting it to be an unknown Latin word. That European languages have appropriated so much Latin just makes it harder to recognize anything as distinctly Latin. Also, I'm from Norway.

Comment: @Fax: Then it surprises me even more!